# React Native, (using responsive grid) issue with component being way too large

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

By the way I'm using Native Base for the card components, and react-native-responsive-grid for the grid.

http://prntscr.com/kbi48m

Here's the code chunk. Basically it sets up a horizontal box (Row) that has two columns in it. Each column has one card component in it. If the screen is <= small size, the columns get a width of 99% of the screen and stack on top of one another. If the screen is big enough, both column get rendered side by side with a width of 50% each.

When in landscape view, the sizing of the Card component vertically appears normally (I manually set width of card to 100% so it takes the full width of it's container). (It's just as big as it needs to be to fit the text field inside: http://prntscr.com/kbi5q4

In portrait mode, suddenly the cards get a massive height. Much taller than the child elements need: http://prntscr.com/kbi6o7

I tried to hard code the height of the cards which works fine for either landscape, or portrait, but not both. Ive never seen a parent component give a ridiculous amount of extra spacing on one side of its child like this before.

Any insight?

Comment: Please share you components code here